# Why does nvm work with Git cmd but not Windows cmd?

Tags: git, cmd, nvm

I installed nvm using the Windows installer, and all of the `nvm` commands work in the Git CMD, but don't work in the Windows CMD:

> 'nvm' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Why / how did the Git CMD automatically pick up on the installation but Windows CMD didn't?

Comment: As a simple sanity check, compare the `PATH` of both environments. `echo %PATH%` for the Windows command line, `echo $PATH` for Git Bash.

Comment: to run `npm`, use `call npm`, since I think it's a batch script on its own (this doesn't solve the path issue though, of course)...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the reason for "X is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41454769/what-is-the-reason-for-x-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command)

Comment: @Mofi, @Selaron, I don't think that's a good duplicate in this case. nvm is a _bash script_, not a binary program. Fixing the `PATH` won't make it run on `cmd.exe`.

Comment: OP, I can't find a Windows installer for nvm. Are you using something else, like [nvm-windows](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows) (an unrelated but similar tool written in Go)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The comments focusing on your `%PATH%` may be relevant, but they only point to a small part of the problem. In this case I think they're more misleading than helpful.

[nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) is a

> Simple **bash script** to manage multiple active node.js versions

(bold added)

nvm isn't exactly a standalone program, and (perhaps surprisingly) it isn't written in JavaScript. It's a script written for [bash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell)), the default shell on most Linux machines (though it [also works with zsh](https://github.com/creationix/nvm#zsh) and may work on other related shells like the Bourne shell). On Windows, Git comes with Bash and I strongly suspect when you say "Git CMD" you really mean that Bash shell.

Windows' `cmd.exe` is a completely different animal. PowerShell is closer to bash than `cmd.exe`, but it's still very different and scripts aren't compatible between the two.

This is a bit like asking why a Perl script doesn't run on Python. They're simply different languages.